# Paste Macro-Increase speed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How do i make this macro faster?

Windows("THe").Activate
    Sheets("The2").Select

```
Range("H8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIFS('Google'!C8,'Googe'!C1,RC21,'Google'!C5,RC1)"
Range("H8").Select
Selection.Copy
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 3):

1) [**Avoid using Select/Active statements**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

2) use With block

3) apply formula to entire range at once (instead copy/paste)

```
With Workbooks("THe").Sheets("The2")
    .Range("H8:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS('Google'!C8,'Googe'!C1,RC21,'Google'!C5,RC1)"
End With
```

and also don't use `xlDown`, use `xlUp` instead: [**How to determine last used row/column**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)